# Wait for Meteor.user() to completely load before template renders

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

This has been asked before however, I don't feel I've seen a suitable answer. I'm currently using `{{ #if currentUser.emails.[0].verified }} show data {{else}} please verify email {{/if}}` on the layout template check whether or not the user has verified their email. In this scenario, I get a flicker between the screens if the user has registered because meteor.user() hasn't loaded completely so `currentUser.emails.[0].verified` returns null and changes to true once it has loaded completely.

Is there a way I can wait for Meteor.userId to completely load before the template renders without using delay?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can force the Template.subscriptionsReady to wait for the Meteor.user() data (so that when the Template.subscriptionsReady is true, the currentUser logic is also up-to-date and won't change) by adding a stub subscription.

I added the following Subscription and then subscribed to this from the template:

```
Meteor.publish('userWait', function () {

  return null;

});
```

**Here's a more detailed description of why this issue was popping up**:
When loading a template, if you're only relying native handler for currentUser - then currentUser will always initially load *false* (in the template logic) and then will load *true* once the data load is complete.

Adding logic to show a loading state that relies on Template.subscriptionsReady will only work if there is an additional Subscription for the template (Template.subscriptionsReady doesn't acknowledge the automatic subscriptions for the user data).

For me, this meant that the internal pages will always prompt a login before realizing that the user was already logged in ... which was an ugly UX.

Once I added a Subscription to the template, even though it returned nothing, then Template.subscriptionsReady would wait until Meteor.user() data was available before returning as *true*.

Answer (score 3):

The meteor embedded "currentUser" helper can let you know when the user collection is ready:

`{{#if currentUser}}
   // Do my stuff
{{else}}
   Checking...   // You can also show a spinner image or GIF here

{{/if}}`

Comment: Isn't `{{ #if currentUser.emails.[0].verified }}` the same as `{{#if currentUser}}` exepet I'm asking for it to wait for a specific field.

Comment: Is not the same.   currentUser could return true and currentUser.emails.[0].verified still false.   You should add the {{#if currentUser.emails.[0].verified}} inside {{#if currentUser}}

Comment: Ok, that works. Such a simple solution. Thanks. Should I wrap that in `{{#if Template.subscriptionsReady}}`

Comment: You should use `{{if Template.subsciptionReady}}` to check the availability of other collections, but for `users` collection is not necessary since `currentUser` do the job (Unless you are allowing not signed in users to surf your app and reach the template where you are verifying the email).

Answer (score 0):

Typically, you can use [`Template.subscriptionsReady`](http://blazejs.org/api/templates.html#Blaze-TemplateInstance-subscribe) in your Template to wrap code that depends upon subscribed data.  Since Meteor handles the publish/subscribe of currentUser automatically, I'm not sure if this method will work or not.  Give it a try and let me know.

Example.

```
{{#if Template.subscriptionsReady}}
  {{ #if currentUser.emails.[0].verified }} show data {{else}} please verify email {{/if}}
{{/if}}
```

Comment: Yes, I've tried this, however, the subscription is considered ready even though all the user's data hasn't been fully received/loaded. This causes the app to flip between screens as the data is gradually loaded. It's only a split second however it's terrible for user experience.

Answer (score 0):

What I have found to work well for me is to subscribe to the user in the wait in a waitOn function in iron router:

```
Router.route('/',{
        waitOn: [
            function() { 
                if (!Meteor.userId()) {
                  Router.go("/login");
                }
                return Meteor.subscribe('currUser');
            },

        ],
        ...
})
```

Comment: Is iron router? In using flowrouter

Comment: using iron router